# $compile not triggering ng-click in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am generating dynamic html element from angularjs controller.I have used $compile 
to make ng-click work inside html element.But still it is not calling the function.

Here is my js

```
    var accountApp = angular.module('accountApp', ['ngRoute']);
    accountApp.config(['$compileProvider',function($compileProvider )
    .controller('myController',function($scope,$compile) 
    {
      var searchHTML = '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-
      click="setMarkerToCenterA()">'+item.title+'</a></li>';
      $compile(searchHTML)($scope);

      $scope.setMarkerToCenterA = function() {
      alert("this alert is not calling");
    }
   });
  }]);
```

I have injected the dependencies also.Can anyone tell why ng-click is not calling function even though i am using $compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need an element where this li element will be located.

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Then in your controller:

```
var element = angular.element("#list");
element.html($compile(html)($scope));

$scope.setMarkerToCenterA = function() {
    alert("Here");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you missed to parse the HTML string using `angular.element(htmlString)` which is then compiled.

```js
var app = angular.module('stackoverflow', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile, $sce) {

  var searchHTML = '<a href="#" data-ng-click="setMarkerToCenterA()">hello</a>';
  var template = angular.element(searchHTML);
  $compile(template)($scope);

  angular.element(document.querySelector('#container')).append(template);

  $scope.setMarkerToCenterA = function() {
    alert("this alert is now calling");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div  ng-app="stackoverflow" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```